# vb.net unable to Console.SetWindowPosition

Tags: vb.net, position, window, console-application

I'm creating a Windows Console application in VB.NET, and I am unable to set the window position relative to the screen. In short, I want a function to centre the window to the screen.

I have tried to use `Console.SetWindowPosition(w, h)` method and `Console.WindowTop`, `Console.WindowLeft` properties. When returning the values for `WindowTop` and `WindowLeft`, they both return 0, and if I attempt to change these values with `Console.WindowLeft = n` (n > 0), the program throws an OutOfBounds exception, stating that the Window's size must fit within the console's buffer.

I run `Console.SetWindowSize(80, 35)` and `Console.SetBufferSize(80, 35)` before attempting to position the window, yet it still throws the exception if `n` is greater than 0. When returning both `WindowTop` and `WindowLeft` values, both of them are 0, even if the console window has been moved before returning those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods that you are calling don't work with the Console window, but with the character buffer that is showed by the console window. If you want to move the console window I am afraid that you need to use Windows API

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Drawing
Module Module1

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
      ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, _
      ByVal X As Integer, _
      ByVal Y As Integer, _
      ByVal cx As Integer, _
      ByVal cy As Integer, _
      ByVal uFlags As UInteger) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Function GetSystemMetrics(ByVal smIndex As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim handle As IntPtr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
        Center(handle, New System.Drawing.Size(500, 400))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub Center(ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal sz As System.Drawing.Size)

        Dim SWP_NOZORDER = &H4
        Dim SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40
        Dim SM_CXSCREEN = 0
        Dim SM_CYSCREEN = 1

        Dim width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
        Dim height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)

        Dim leftPos = (width - sz.Width) / 2
        Dim topPos = (height - sz.Height) / 2

        SetWindowPos(handle, 0, leftPos, topPos, sz.Width, sz.Height, SWP_NOZORDER Or SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
    End Sub

End Module
```

This code doesn't take in consideration the presence of a second monitor

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's unfortunate that console applications lack in being able to ideally manipulate the window position.