# How to keep text at the top of console?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I'm trying to have my console application automatically scroll but keep the text at the top. The text history must be accessible so `Console.Clear` isn't viable.

Is there any method to detect when console scrolls or any method to adjust the current Y pos, as I know console will scroll when your text is about to be off-screen. I'd like this same effect, but to keep the newest line at the top of the window. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't really understand what you describe in english, but maybe you can use `Console.SetCursorPosition()`.

Comment: @OlivierRogier `SetCursorPosition` only sets the position of the _cursor_ but it doesn't scroll the contents. The OP (as I understand) wants the same effect as manually scrolling to only show the top line.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed So the OP needs to get the console windows handle and use scrollbars' WinAPIs ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277563/how-do-i-get-the-handle-of-a-console-applications-window & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/scrolling-the-screen-buffer & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/scrolling-a-screen-buffer-s-window

Comment: @OlivierRogier Not really. `Console.SetWindowPosition()` does that for you. Note that a "window" here doesn't mean the actual Console window itself. See my answer below for more info.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Ok, your result animation seems to be good and now I understand the OP question.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the [`Console.SetWindowPosition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setwindowposition) method. <sup>*</sup>

> Parameters
>   `left` Int32
>   The column position of the upper left corner of the console window.
>
> `top` Int32
>   The row position of the upper left corner of the console window.

Here's an example to demonstrate:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.ReadKey(false);
        Console.WriteLine($"You are currently at line #{++i}");
        Console.SetWindowPosition(0, i - 1);
    }
}
```

#### Result:

[image: Scroll Console to Top]

Note that if you're getting close to the value of `Console.BufferHeight`, you could get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, that is, when the new position (top) is greater than `Console.BufferHeight - Console.WindowHeight`, so you might want to take that into account. I would add a simple condition to handle this case. Example:

```
int newTop = i - 1;
if (newTop + Console.WindowHeight <= Console.BufferHeight)
{
    Console.SetWindowPosition(0, newTop);
}
```

..but you might want to handle this differently (e.g., increase the buffer as you go, change the window size, etc.)

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Don't be mislead by the name of the method. A "window" here doesn't mean the actual desktop/console window in OS terms (borders, etc.). Instead, it refers to the currently displayed *window* of the character buffer. To move the *actual console window*, you'd have to use the `SetWindowPos` Windows API function. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33456602/8967612).</sub>

Comment: I think the OP is asking for setting the position of the text, not the window position of the console.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono This code does exactly what you just described.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I know, that's why I upvoted the answer and was trying to clear things up. But I think the confusion is mostly because `SetWindowPosition` is a confusing name for this method as it does not actually affect the desktop window. You might want to add this from its documentation to the answer

Comment: I upvoted cause I like it, the only one bad thing is the old text flashing when you add a new line

Comment: @BiesiGrr I know that the name can be a little confusing but "window" here doesn't mean the actual console window. I added an update to the answer to make that clear.

Comment: the downside of using `SetWindowPosition` is its limitation to the Windows platform.  this is not working in .NetCore on Linux system yet (tested with Core3.1.1)

Comment: @AliReza Yes, that is documented. If the OS isn't Windows, you get a PlatformNotSupportedException. This question is tagged [.net], not [.net-core] though.