# how to get visual studio to remember .net console app's window position and size, each debug or operation session

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Every time I do F5, I have to reposition the black console window back over to my other monitor.

[image]

Comment: Hi, maybe this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456055/vb-net-unable-to-console-setwindowposition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right-click black window title bar > Props.. > Layout tab > uncheck Let system position window > OK

Comment: That works.  But the only problem I sometimes see is the uncheck sometimes unsticks.